# android locale change in orientation change

Tags: android, configuration, orientation, locale

in my app i am having two activities one is rotatable to both sides and other is locked in landscape mode.

Following is my manifest file details where the activities been added

```
<activity
    android:name="com.hogaming.android.Activities.LoginActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden">
</activity>

<activity
    android:name="com.android.activities.MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden">
</activity>
```

in my login activity using a spinner i am changing the locale and updating entire edit texts and buttons text. 
In a button click action i am updating the UI views and that time when i rotate the device, the English locale is set on views which are updated
Here is my entire code

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity 
{
    Locale locale = null;
    Spinner langSpinner;
    private SharedPreferences langPrefs;
    String langSelected = "";
    int langPosition = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.loginscreen);

        langPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        langSelected = langPrefs.getString(langPrefKey, "");
        langPosition = langPrefs.getInt(langPosKey, 0);

        langSpinner = (Spinner)this.findViewById(R.id.lanuage_spinner1);
        langSpinner.setSelection(langPosition);
        langSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long arg3) 
            {   
                if (pos == 0) 
                {
                    langSelected ="en";
                    locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
                }
                else if (pos == 1) 
                {
                    langSelected ="it";
                    locale = Locale.ITALIAN;
                } 
                else if (pos == 2) 
                {
                    langSelected ="zh";
                    locale = Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE;
                }               
                else if (pos == 3)
                {
                    langSelected ="zh-rTW";
                    locale = Locale.TRADITIONAL_CHINESE;
                }
                changeLang(langSelected, pos);
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }   
        });

        btnLogin = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.LoginButton);
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new ButtonClickListener());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        this.finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() 
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        this.finish();
    }

    public class ButtonClickListener implements OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View v) {
                    final LoginTask validateTask = new LoginTask(context, usernameField.getText().toString(), passwordField.getText().toString());
                    validateTask.execute();
                }

                // Hide the keyboard
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(passwordField.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

    public class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> 
    {
        protected LoginActivity context;
        protected Exception exception;
        private String username;
        private String password;

        public LoginTask(LoginActivity context, String uname, String pwd) {
            this.context = context;
            this.username = uname;
            this.password = pwd;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try 
            {
                return HTTPHelper.LoginTaskData(this.context, username, password);
            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                exception = e;
                Log.e(TAG, "Login Task Error", e);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Log.e(TAG, "LoginTask: " + result);
            if (result.equals("true")) 
            {
                // moves to next activity
            }
            else if (result.equals("false"))
            {
                //showing an alert textview with selected language text
            }
        }
    }

    public void changeLang(String lang, int pos)
    {
        if (lang.length() != 0)
        {       
            saveLocale(lang, pos, locale);
            android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            updateTexts();
        }
    }

    public void saveLocale(String lang, int pos, Locale locale)
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = langPrefs.edit();
        editor1.remove(langPrefKey);
        editor1.remove(langPosKey);
        editor1.commit();

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = langPrefs.edit();
        editor.putString(langPrefKey, lang);
        editor.putInt(langPosKey, pos);
        editor.commit();

        langSelected = langPrefs.getString(langPrefKey, "");
        langPosition = langPrefs.getInt(langPosKey, 0);
    }

    private void updateTexts()
    {
        // here i will once again set all textview String values, it changes to the selected language
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration newConfig) 
    {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if (locale != null){
            newConfig.locale = locale;
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(newConfig, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What Android OS you are using?

Comment: android kitkat and lollypop

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you correctly, the issue is that the phone's locale is restored when you switch the screen orientation, despite you have `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"`, in your `AndroidManifest.xml`. If I were in you I would approach the issue from a different perspective. I would get rid of the `android:configChanges`, letting android do its job restarting the Activity, when the orientation changes. I would then use the pair `onSaveInstanceState`, to save and the `Locale` the user selected in the `Spinner`. When `onCreate` is called again, and you know is called due to the orientation change because the bundle is not null, read the `Locale` stored and restart, and update the configuration again. E.g.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putSerializable("LOCALE", locale);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.loginscreen);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        locale = (Locale) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("LOCALE");
        if (locale != null) {
           // update the configuration 
        }
    }
```

Comment: It should work, but I don't know why it is not working in my case. I followed all the steps.

Answer (score 1):

You still have the solution. just set the saved locale. in the `onCreate`:

```
    ...
    langPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    langSelected = langPrefs.getString(langPrefKey, "");
    langPosition = langPrefs.getInt(langPosKey, 0);

    // JUST ADD THIS LINE HERE
    changeLang(langSelected, langPosition);  
    // no need to check empty langSelected, it handled inside of changeLang as you write.

    langSpinner = (Spinner)this.findViewById(R.id.lanuage_spinner1);
    ....
```

maybe you need to remove `android:configChanges` and its corresponding method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put following code when fixed orientation of particular activity in manifest file:

```
<activity
     android:name="Your_Activity"
     android:configChanges="orientation"
     android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your activity

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setlocal();// the code for setting your local
}
```