# How to prevent language change when changing screen orientation

Tags: android, android-activity, config, screen-orientation, setlocale

In the app I have three buttons that change the language in the application:

[PL]

```
setLocale("pl");
```

[DE]

```
setLocale("de");
```

[EN]

```
setLocale("en");

public void setLocale(String lang) {

    myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = myLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    Intent refresh = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(refresh);

    this.finish();

}
```

In one place, in my application, I change the orientation of the screen to the horizontal (there is only one activity in the application). And here comes the problem. Changing the orientation of the screen changes the language to the default setting in the phone. 
I tried to add the following entry in the AndroidManifest file - but it does not work.

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"

    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
```

Searching for SO also gave nothing
I will be grateful to help resolve this issue.
Regards
Marcin

Comment: try this - `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"`

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does not work. The effect is the same as before

Comment: check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/a/30162104/6244429

Comment: OK, but what I have to write in condition insteadif (myLocale != null)? I do not want to reload the activity again

Answer (score 0):

Please store the `Locale` that you want to use in persistent type of storage, and restore it in your `onCreate`. You could even have a piece of code to reset the Locale to default in `onStop` if you want it to persist orientation change but not app restart!

For example, you could store the Locale in a SharedPreferences, along with all your app's other config data. If you don't know about SharedPreferences, there are many tutorials on Google!

Comment: I do not think I understand. Could you give us a piece of code as it looks?

Comment: ok, thanks. But how prevent restart app belong change locale?

Comment: On restart, set locale to value of Preference.

Comment: But I would not like to reset the app. Is there such an option?

Comment: No, unfortunately Android doesn't allow this.